# apt-get won't upgrade old generic-pae

Tags: apt, upgrade

Running #apt-get upgrade I am told to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.  I do that and see:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 138 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,460 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-pae:
 linux-headers-generic-pae depends on linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-headers-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.48.58); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-headers-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.48.58); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-headers-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's a listing of my `/usr/src`:

```
/usr/src:
total used in directory 88 available 19619852
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Feb  1 23:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Aug 31  2012 ..
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan 18  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-36
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan 18  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb  1  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-37
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb  1  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 22  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-38
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 22  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Mar 19  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-39
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Mar 19  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Apr  9  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-40
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Apr  9  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 May  2  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-41
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 May  2  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 May 16  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-43
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 May 16  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 May 24  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-44
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 May 24  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 May 31  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-45
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 May 31  2013 linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb  1 23:21 linux-headers-3.2.0-58
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb  1 23:21 linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
```

Most of my other machines have all the numbers in there between 45 and 58 also.  I don't think I even need this 48 version do I?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: you can just keep the latest kernel that works good.. check the kernel currently use with `uname -r`.. also visit this link for more about removing older kernels: [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions, to clean up the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: both http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu won't help in this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing or Forcely removing the corresponding package for the below type of error will solve the problem,

```
dpkg: error package-name (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

In this question `leaving unconfigured` error happens for these three packages,

```
linux-image-generic-pae
linux-headers-generic-pae
linux-generic-pae
```

So we have to remove the packages by running,

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-generic-pae
sudo dpkg -r linux-headers-generic-pae
sudo dpkg -r linux-generic-pae
```

If there was any dependency problem occurs while removing the above then go for `force` option like below else skip it.

**Note:** Go for force option only when  all other methods won't work.

Forcely remove the above three packages by running the below commands,

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-generic-pae
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq linux-headers-generic-pae
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq linux-generic-pae
```

Now you may run an upgrade,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you want the packages to be reinstalled,then run the below

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-pae
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae
```

Comment: There were two problems.  First, old kernels didn't get removed, so my partition filled up.  Second, I suppose an upgrade failed badly, leaving dependencies that were messed up.

Comment: I had seen threads showing this answer, but they were for applications, not system internals, so I had been afraid to blithely remove linux-generic-pae and its kin.