# "Oracle JDK 7 Is NOT installed" error?

Tags: installation, jdk, oracle

I'm trying to install JDK7 on ubuntu 12.4.

In the first try, the power has gone and the laptop shutdown in the middle of downloading JDK7 using terminal as I was using the next terminal commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

when the power returned and I tried to install JDK7 again there was a problem with the lock but I fixed it using the following commands after restarting the machine

```
sudo apt-get install whatever
```

after that I tried installing again using the three commands above, the first was done with no errors and the second too,

but the third command downloaded the package successfully but an error appeared

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched for solutions for this error and found some, tried the following instructions

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer* 
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer* 
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java* 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

tried again but the same "Oracle JDK7 is NOT installed" error appeared.

tried `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
salahuddin@salahuddin:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for salahuddin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 259 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u51-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-02-03 16:28:51--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 41.128.128.35, 41.128.128.40
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|41.128.128.35|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2014-02-03 16:28:51--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.48.230.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.48.230.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz?AuthParam=1391437853_a122991b0aaf032ed8c2812472d1c92c [following]
--2014-02-03 16:28:53--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz?AuthParam=1391437853_a122991b0aaf032ed8c2812472d1c92c
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|41.128.128.35|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Don't know how to fix it

please help

thanks in advance

Comment: one more thing,post the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Run the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I was doing another installation while waiting for your answer, now I pressed Ctrl+Z to quit it, and when typed the first instruction you suggest it worked with no errors, the second one was endded with

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: don't use ctrl+z,use ctrl+c to cancel the installation.Try this command to remove the lock `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` then run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I tried Ctrl+C first but doesn't work, but Ctrl+Z worked

Comment: I've removed the lock and tried the two instructions again

salahuddin@salahuddin:~$ sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching oracle-java7-installer
salahuddin@salahuddin:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.

Is it installed now?

Comment: I think now your problem was solved.Did you run this command `sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer` two times?

Comment: Yeah, the first time it worked but the second instruction didn't, the second time, the output I posted in the previous comment was generated.. would you edit your answer to explain what was the problem and how you solved it, thanks for your time

Comment: did you want to know how do i did this?then see http://askubuntu.com/a/414365/202806

Comment: bad news, When I typed "java -version" in the terminal to see if jdk is installed, the answer was "no "

salahuddin@salahuddin:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

so I'm trying "sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer" again

Comment: now try to install java by running the first three commands which was on your question.That's all.

Comment: are the first and the second commands are mandatory, as I directly typed the third one and it's downloading the package now

Comment: yes,try the 3rd one directly.

Answer (score 5):

I have another potential workaround for this, but it requires manual intervention.  The reason this has broken is because Oracle wants you to accept an OTN license. Here is workaround:

Go to Oracle Java7 JDK download site (I found it at [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)).  Agree to the OTN agreement, then find the file named "**jdk-7u(whateverupdateislatest)-linux-x64.tar.gz**"

```
sudo mv jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/



 sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your download is corrupted .
you have to remove the corrupted package first by code :

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
```

Clean your apt :

```
sudo apt clean
```

Remove and reimport the ropsitory :

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Install your package again :

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Enjoy it bro !
if the problem hasn't solved try using VPN . Maybe there is a filtering between you and the oracle website

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/jdk-7u51-linux-*.tar.gz`

If it is small (~5000 bytes) - then it contains text telling you to accept the OTN license.

If you can, switch to `oracle-java8-installer`

See http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2014/03/15/oracle-adds-license-to-java7-installer-fails