# mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_91’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91’: Directory not empty

Tags: package-management, java, dpkg

I'm trying to install Heroku locally into my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

But I'm getting this error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 heroku
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 14,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Fetched 14,6 MB in 3s (4.497 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package heroku.
(Reading database ... 333239 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../heroku_5.6.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking heroku (5.6.8-1) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_91’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91’: Directory not empty
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up heroku (5.6.8-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone encountered this problem? And how to fix it? For the moment I was thinking to change the owner and the group for these two directories, but I don't know the implications.

Thank you for any suggestions!

LE

I forgot to mention the structure of these two directories:

```
6952928 drwxr-xr-x  9 uucp  143      4096 iul 22 19:41 java-8-oracle
6832129 drwxr-xr-x  8 uucp  143      4096 apr  1  2016 jdk1.8.0_91
```

which looks strange to me. Especially that `uucp 143`. If you need me to provide more info, please ask, as I'm not so advanced in Linux (or such).

Again, thanks!

LE2:

After following @Zanna 's idea, I renamed those two directories, and I ran the installer again. Unsuccessfull, as I get the following error:

```
heroku is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
install: cannot stat ‘javaws-wrapper.sh’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

LE3

Yes, I'm using a ppa. 
I tried [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/121236/410735) steps to purge the package: 
I installed ppa-purge, then I ran the second command to remove it. I got this error:

```
# First I installed ppa-purge, and at the end, I got the same error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc tasksel debtags libcwidget-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
  ppa-purge
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2.555 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libboost-iostreams1.54.0 amd64 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 [29,0 kB]
Get:2 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libept1.4.12 amd64 1.0.12 [142 kB]
Get:3 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main aptitude-common all 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 [700 kB]
Get:4 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libcwidget3 amd64 0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1 [307 kB]
Get:5 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main aptitude amd64 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 [1.371 kB]
Get:6 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe ppa-purge all 0.2.8+bzr57 [5.704 B]
Fetched 2.555 kB in 3s (670 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 333239 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-iostreams1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64 (1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libept1.4.12:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.4.12_1.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude-common.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude-common (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcwidget3.
Preparing to unpack .../libcwidget3_0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ppa-purge.
Preparing to unpack .../ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr57_all.deb ...
Unpacking ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr57) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_91’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91’: Directory not empty
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64 (1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Setting up aptitude-common (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up aptitude (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/aptitude-curses to provide /usr/bin/aptitude (aptitude) in auto mode
Setting up ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr57) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

# Here I tried to purge the package

sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: webupd8team java
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: webupd8team java
```

And now I can't understand why this warning, as [both directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmF5W.jpg) are in place.
Additionaly, I got this [error window](https://imgur.com/LqXKDcu) too.

Comment: the cause of that error is most likely that there is already a directory named `jdk1.8.0_91` at that location which is not empty. `mv` refuses to overwrite the directory in that case (by design). Perhaps you could rename the existing directory temporarily, to see if that fixes things without causing new problems. I do not know what your underlying issue is, but I wouldn't recommend any `chown` commands based on the current information. You should tell us what you have been doing that might have caused problems.

Comment: Yes I realise that you are not executing it, however, you can still avoid *that particular error* by renaming `java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91`... I do not know the full path, but you can do `mv /path/to/java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91{,.bak}` and then try running the installation again. (correct the `/path/to` part with the real path) but I don't know what side effects there could be - you might have to rename it back to correct new problems that arise. And this may not be your root problem

Comment: @Zanna Ok, I'll try to rename it and re-install again. The same happened, some time ago, when I tried to install other software based on java, like PhpStorm, or to un-install Chrome. The error was identical. I'll let you know if will work or not.

Comment: @Zanna Done. But by renaming the dirs, I couldn't solve the problem...

Comment: @Zanna Can you please take a look again to my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for pinging me! OK, looking at your new error, it seems `heroku` is fine, and the problem is the `oracle-java8-installer` package. Are you using the webupda8 team PPA? I suggest trying to purge the ppa if so, or purge `oracle-java8-installer`. Try running `sudo apt install -f` afterwards. If you can't manage to get rid of it, please update us again

Comment: @Zanna Please check my LE3.

Comment: This question looks similar ["Oracle JDK 7 Is NOT installed" error?](//askubuntu.com/q/414885)

Comment: @Zanna Yes. I was finally able to uninstall oracle-java8-installer (without getting any error). My last question: should I reinstall it? This is a dependency for some clients, dunno, like PhpStorm, Chromium, even the heroku package I wanted to install initialy? Thank you for support.

Comment: can't those packages use OpenJDK instead? if not, go ahead and try re-adding the PPA, hopefully it will work out, and if not you know how to fix it :S When you're done, you can write an answer to your own question :D

Comment: @Zanna I'll write an answer only if you don't want to post one. And please do, as I'll accept it as the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your answer will be much better than mine as you know in detail what you did to solve your complex problem :) please ping me when you answer so I can give you an upvote.

Comment: @Zanna Done... :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Zanna's help, I was able to fix my problem. And because there are a lot of replies in the comment area below the original post, I'll say once more what my problem was:

I was trying to install Heroku CLI, but I couldn't, as an error came up at the end:

```
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_91’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_91’: Directory not empty
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up heroku (5.6.8-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So the fix was by using two simple terminal commands (which in turn purges the oracle-java8-installer, which caused the problem), as [this nice](https://askubuntu.com/a/414889/410735) post recommends:

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then I tried again to install Heroku CLI and it worked like a charm.

If you then need to reinstall `oracle-java8-installer`, you'll need to add again the `webupd8team ppa`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I must mention that I was able to install Heroku CLI without reinstalling `oracle-java8-installer`.

Now, if you think upvoting this answer, you'll need to thank to @Zanna, more than to my researches.

Merry Christmas all :)

Comment: well done for solving your problem and thanks for posting a great clear answer :) Merry Christmas